# Asterisk Event PauseQueueMember - AMI Calls

Tags: asterisk

We use Asterisk-AMI and we have a little JS server which listens for Events from the AMI to gather & display statistics (Calls, Queues etc).

I initialy thought that when a queue member is paused, the `QueueMemberPaused` event is called with Paused attribute signalling wether they are paused or unpaused.

However its come to my attention that the total number of queue members paused that is calculated by the server is not true. I know that the event `Newexten` can give the attribute `application` value of `RemoveQueueMember` & `AddQueueMember`, I'm thinking that it might also give the value of `PausedQueueMember` but unfortunately I have not had the best time with the documentation provided (it isn't very well structured).

What I am really looking for is an event flow that shows what the AMI puts out when actions happen.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is an undocumented event called `QueueMember`.
Within this event you'll find the `paused` attribute.

In my case, this event was used as the total queue member counter, at which was adding all queue members to the non-paused count on the server.

Here is my source: http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=83884